# Prevent default anchor behaviour AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the user clicks a link, I want to execute some code in a function inside the controller. But I want to prevent that the URL changes.

**I tried the following possibilities**

1. Removed the href-attribute. *Didn't work, still changes the url to '/'*
2. Tried `ng-click='deleteUser(user.id, $event)'` and `$event.preventDefault()` in my deleteUser()-function. *Didn't work.*
3. What did work is a hack I've found on GitHub about an [unintended reload](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1225).

This is how I do it now:

```
<a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" href="javascript:">Delete user</a>
```

**Question**

What is the'clean' method to prevent a link from changing the URL?

Comment: Why don't use href="#" ?

Comment: Or just ```href=""```?

Comment: +1 to opyate, `href=""` fixed my problem. `href="#"` re-routes to `#/` so it redirected on click.

Comment: The problem with using `href=""` is that the you can no longer tab to that anchor with the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is in the [a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js)

That's right, every `<a></a>` element is actually an AngularJS directive.

It seems to fix some issues with IE if you look the comments in the code.

But everything for me is working great when I just removed the directive from the AngularJS core code.

I was having the same problem as you did and tried all of the other solutions. The difference is that I had the problem only in IE.

If you don't want to play with building the AngularJS script from source, just search for htmlAnchorDirective in the angular.js file and remove/comment it out.

I believe there is a bigger problem here which should be addressed in the AngularJS core, but I haven't found it yet.

**UPDATE**: This solution is most probably outdated now! You should try using the latest AngularJS version.

Answer (score 18):

```
<a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" href="">Delete user</a>
```

Comment: same as I said for the answer of Dan Caragea, an empty href doesn't do the trick for me

Comment: I don't believe this behaviour is inconsistent between browsers, or cases. Can you provide your not working live example, possiblly on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Left href="" and all worked as expected. I don't know why but I guess I was expecting magic out of ng-click.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js#L30) for the `a` element directive (which is a part of the Angular core), it states at line 29 - 31:

```
if (!element.attr(href)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Which means Angular already is solving the issue of links without a href. The only issue you still have is the css problem. You can still apply the pointer style to anchors that have ng-clicks, e.g.:

```
a[ng-click] {
    /* Styles for anchors without href but WITH ng-click */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

So, you could even make your site more accessible by marking real links with a subtle, different styling then links that perform functions.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

What exactly didn't work when you removed the href attribute?
That's exactly what you should do. See this fiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/SXcQN/

Comment: an empty href of ng-href didn't do the trick for me. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Maybe you can provide a simplified jsfiddle and/or browser details...or does this happen in all browsers?

Answer (score 2):

As @Justus pointed out, if the source code is like:

```
if (!element.attr(href)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Making `element.attr(href)` as **null string** `''` should get you inside the `if` condition, as `!''` evaluates to `true`. That is the solution by @umur

Answer (score 1):

I have always been doing deleteUser($event,user.id) and it seemed to work. A possible problem would be the ordering of the variables to your click handler. The first argument should probably be the $event object.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't seem to work for me. I just tried it with `$event` as the first variable, but doesn't work. Thx for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I use my custom directive to accomplish this. Its mechanism is to operate ng-click directive itself.

```
angular.module('delete', [])
.directive('buttonDelete', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    var confirmFunc = function (scope, element, attr, event, ngClick) {
        if (! confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            // Copy from ngEventDirectives initialization.
            var fn = $parse(ngClick);
            scope.$apply(function() {
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
            });
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        compile: function (element, attr) {
            var ngClick = attr.ngClick;
            attr.ngClick = '';

            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    element.click(function (e) {
                        confirmFunc(scope, element, attr, e, ngClick);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly a hack, but I did:

```
<span class="link" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete user</span>
```

and in my css had

```
span.link {
    /* style like a link */
}
```

Comment: I also assigned a class to my link (with Jade, together with Node.js) but didn't do the trick. Thank you for you response!

Answer (score 0):

The following worked great for me:

```
<a ng-href="javascript: return false;" ng-click="alertSearchCtrl.deleteAlert()">Remove</a>
```